# What is the "Leave" option on the power menu in lubuntu?

Tags: lubuntu

In the default panel on Lubuntu (LXQT Desktop), there are multiple power options:

[image: Leave option screenshot]

What does the "Leave" option do?

Comment: I don't have it, but it uses the same icon as "Shutdown" so that seems a reasonable guess.

Comment: Yeah it doesn’t do anything it’s weird

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of searching led me to the GitHub repository for LXQT and [this issue about customizing the 'Leave' options](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt/issues/876).

So the repo contains the [lxqt-leave.desktop.in](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-session/blob/master/lxqt-leave/resources/lxqt-leave.desktop.in) file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Leave
GenericName=Leave
Comment=Leave dialog
Exec=lxqt-leave
Icon=system-shutdown
Categories=System;X-Leave;
OnlyShowIn=LXQt;
```

Comparing that to the [lxqt-shutdown.desktop.in](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-session/blob/master/lxqt-leave/resources/lxqt-shutdown.desktop.in) file:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Shutdown
GenericName=Shutdown
Comment=shutdown the machine
Exec=lxqt-leave --shutdown
Icon=system-shutdown
Categories=System;X-Leave;
OnlyShowIn=LXQt;
```

There is a difference in the Exec argument here. While 'Shutdown' specifies `lxqt-leave --shutdown`, the 'Leave' option simply runs `lxqt-leave`.

So what is the behaviour then? The [man page](https://github.com/lxqt/lxqt-session/blob/master/lxqt-leave/resources/lxqt-leave.1) has some information on this:

> lxqt-leave is a graphical Qt tool for easily triggering leave session
>   actions: logout, reboot, shutdown, hibernate, and lock screen. If run
>   with an argument, the dialog is not shown and the action is executed
>   directly.

So the documentation says the the 'Leave' option (which is equivalent to running `lxqt-leave`) should give you a dialog from which you'd be able to select login & power management options, such as logout, hibernate, shutdown, reboot. I am not a user of Lubuntu, so I can't be more specific about why that does not happen for you. Perhaps you can try running `lxqt-leave` from a command-line and see if it works as intended or if it throws an error.